# WordPress - remove menu item added by plugin for non-admins

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

How can I remove the following menu item added by a plugin?

```
admin.php?page=stock-manager
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer to my question...

```
function wpse28782_remove_menu_items() {

if( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ):

remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php', 'stock-manager' );
```

add it to your theme's functions.php

Answer (score 0):

[WP Admin Menu Editor Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) is one of plugins to let you have full control over your `wp-admin` menu.

Comment: that plugin removes the menu item for all users. I want the admins to still see it